# Rails as a backend API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am completely new to rails (actually this is my day 1 of rails). I am trying to develop a backend for my iOS app. Here is my create user method.

```
def create 

    user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])

    if user 
      render :json => {:success => 'false', :message => 'Email already exists'}
    else 
      user = User.new(user_params)
      if user.save
      render :json => {:success => 'true', :message => 'Account has been created'}
      else 
      render :json => {:success => 'false', :message => 'Error creating account'}
      end 
    end 

  end
```

How can I make it better?

Comment: I suggest using more lightweight framework for API implementation, such as "grape"(https://github.com/intridea/grape).

Answer (score 1):

You could use HTTP status code, but it might be overkill if your API is not going to be used by anything but your iOS app.

Comment: HTTP status codes avoid double error checking.  The consuming code will already need to check if the call succeeded or failed.  There's no reason to then again have to check if the "succeeded" call (HTTP 200) actually returned an error message.

Comment: Is there a way I can refactor the messages I am sending back. Like maybe creating a Response class and send that back instead of dynamic no name class.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is to put the validation on the model's side and let ActiveModel populate the errors. Status codes are also super useful.

```
class User < ApplicationModel
  validate_uniqueness_of :email
  # Other useful code
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:email)) # `require` and `permit` is highly recommended to treat params

    if @user.save # `User#save` will use the validation set in the model. It will return a boolean and if there are errors, the `errors` attributes will be populated
      render json: @user, status: :ok # It's good practice to return the created object
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity # you'll have your validation errors as an array
    end
  end
end
```